# How to convert Maybe to Single without "Sequence doesn't contain any elements"

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I am using RxSwift(https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift).

I wrote the following code:

```
let m1 = Maybe<String>.empty()
let m2 = Maybe<String>.just("AA")

let s1 = m1.asObservable().asSingle()
let s2 = m2.asObservable().asSingle()


Single.zip(s1, s2).subscribe(onSuccess: { a, b in
    print("==================")
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print("==================")
}, onError: { e in
    print("EEEEE")
    print(e) // Sequence doesn't contain any elements.
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

An Error `"Sequence doesn't contain any elements"` occurred because `m1` is `Maybe#empty`.

How to covert `Maybe<String>` to `Single<String?>`?

If `Maybe` is `empty`, I'd like to make it `nil.`

In this case, I want the `a` variable to be `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## self resolved

`let s1 = m1.asObservable().first()`

### The Document(Comment) say

```
/**
 The `first` operator emits only the very first item emitted by this Observable,
 or nil if this Observable completes without emitting anything.
 
 - seealso: [single operator on reactivex.io](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/first.html)
 
 - returns: An observable sequence that emits a single element or nil if the source observable sequence completes without emitting any items.
 */
```

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/c6c0c540109678b96639c25e9c0ebe4a6d7a69a9/RxSwift/Traits/ObservableType%2BPrimitiveSequence.swift#L30

### Custom Extension Version

custom extension version I think I do not need,
but if necessary

```
extension Maybe {
    func asOptionalElementSingle() -> Single<Element?> {
        return self.asObservable().first()
    }
}
```